# Bash mysql / public_html only backup script

Tags: linux, bash, backup

On my dedicated, have a 5gig NAS I want to backup to.
Eventually doing a backup of the MySQL tables and public_html of each cPanel,

How could I read the content of the MySQL table folder (/var/lib/mysql) and if sub-folders are found, then make a tar.gz files of those sub-folders found then copy them to /mnt/mysql_backup/date/dbname.

Then go to /home/ and walk through each folder to backup the /public_html/ folder where it exists, then copy files to /mnt/files_backup/date/cpanelfoler

if script is completed successfully.
delete the old backups and keep only the last one just created.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Which bit in particular are you having difficulty with ?

Comment: Using `mysqldump` would be better/easier than backing up `/var/lib/mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

try this script:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash

OK=0          
KO=1

MYSQL_DIR="/var/lib/mysql"
MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR="/mnt/mysql_backup/date/dbname"
HTML_DIR="/home/public_html"
HTML_BACKUP_DIR="/mnt/files_backup/date/cpanelfoler"
LOG_FILE="/tmp/backup_log.log"

function archiving
{
        local return_status=$OK         # Function return status
        local IN_DIR=$1                 # Input directory
        local ARC_DIR=$2                # Archiving directory

        final_arc_dir=$ARC_DIR
        timestamp=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
        # Archive will be like this : archive_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
        final_arc_dir=${final_arc_dir}/archive_$timestamp

        if [ ! -d "$final_arc_dir" ]; then
        echo "Creating directory $final_arc_dir"
        mkdir -p $final_arc_dir
        fi

        # More secure : copy then delete instead of moving
        echo "Copying files ... to $ARC_DIR"
        # For each file, or directory we copy than delete
        cp -r $IN_DIR $final_arc_dir
        return_last_command=`echo $?`
        if [ $return_last_command -ne 0 ]
        then
                return_status=KO
                echo "Error copying files ---> $IN_DIR"
        else
                rm -rf $IN_DIR
        fi

        # Archive name
        archive_name=$(echo $final_arc_dir |  awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
        # We can compress
        tar cvf - $final_arc_dir | gzip > $ARC_DIR/$archive_name.tar.gz
        ret=$?
        if [ $ret -ne 0 ]
        then
                echo "Compression failed ---> $final_arc_dir"
                return_status=$KO
        else
                echo "Compression terminated successfully, we can delete original directory"
                rm -rf $final_arc_dir
        fi

        # Cleanup old archives
        for f in `ls -l $ARC_DIR | awk '{print $9}' | grep -v "$timestamp"`
        do
            echo "\nRemove this older backup --------------------> $f\n"
            rm -rf $ARC_DIR/$f
        done


        return $return_status
}

### MAIN ###

### Archiving MYSQL FILES
if ! archiving $MYSQL_DIR $MYSQL_BACKUP_DIR
then
    echo "\nError archiving MYSQL FILES ----> KO" | tee -a $LOG_FILE
    exit $KO
fi

### Archiving HTML FILES
if ! archiving $HTML_DIR $HTML_BACKUP_DIR
then
    echo "\nError archiving HTML FILES ----> KO" | tee -a $LOG_FILE
    exit $KO
fi

# All seems to be ok
echo "\nAll seems to be okay\n"
exit $OK
```

Comment: Looks great, however wont this create endless "date" folders? is there a way for it to keep only the latest and delete the old if backup was a success?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html):

```
$ mysqldump my_database > my_database_dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

To backup mysql, I would consider using mysqldump. but keep in mind that mysqldump locks the tables while it is running. and if you have fair amount of data in you databases, this process could take quite some time.

If you cannot afford to lock the databases for a long period of time, I would do a mirror and run the backup scripts on that mirror. (here find a detailed step-by-step procedure to do so : http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication)

To backup your databases you could do something like this :

```
BACKUPDATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
BACKUPDIR='/mnt/backup'

BACKUPUSER='bkpUser'
BACKUPPASS='bkpPassword'

mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPDATE/databases/

for DATABASE in $(mysql -u$BACKUPUSER -pBACKUPPASS -e "show databases" | grep -v Database | grep -v  information_schema)
  do 
      mysqldump -u$BACKUPUSER -pBACKUPPASS $DATABASE > $BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPDATE/databases/$DATABASE.sql
  done
```

This should create a new folder everyday and dump all your databases into it.

for the public_html folders, something like

```
tar czvf $BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPDATE/public_html.tar.gz $(find /home/  -type d -name public_html)
```

Add a little error checking and this should get you going.

One last word about backups. I strongly suggest you to keep more then just the last backup files. something like keep every thing for a week and one every month sounds pretty good to me.